# Issue with importing tlb into c++ client code

Tags: c#, com

Suppose I have following definitions :

```
namespace BaseIfsNamespace   //defined in assembly A1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("2E6CB2B7-8884-4250-87A5-83BF52EE5D29")]
    public interface BaseIfs
    {
        void TestM(string s1);
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace DerivedCom  //defined in assembly A2
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("DerivedCom.DerivedCom")]
    [Guid("AC01FD21-4708-4296-9B2E-B268BC1D880B")]
    //[ClassInterface.None]
    public class DerivedCom : BaseIfs
    {
        public void TestM(string s1)
        {
            //Some implementation
        }

    }
}
```

I generate type libraries A1.tlb and A2.tlb correspondingly. But when I use A2 in C++ client code following

```
#import "c:\path11\DerivedCom.tlb" no_namespace raw_interface_only
```

I got error c1084 that typelibrary cannot be imported. 
How correctly should I generate tlbs ( checked with regasm ) and there need somehow to define that A2.tlb depends on tlb1 ? 
I saw related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050057/fatal-error-c1084-cannot-read-type-library-file-smegui-tlb-error-loading-ty) and I know that openning oleview can locally resolve the issue  but i need more common solution ( that will work on the build server )
Thanks in advance

Comment: This should work fine. RegAsm command is just like 'RegAsm.exe a2.dll /tlb:a2.tlb' Any other errors that pop out?

Comment: Quote the **exact** text of the compiler error.  And do not leave ClassInterface.None commented out.

Comment: Here is error message :  fatal error C1084: Cannot read type library file: 'DerivedCom.tlb': Error loading type library/DLL.  I checked , the tlb exists and in projects settings folder containing DerivedCom.tlb added to additional directories list